# How to turn on mongoid logging in console with sinatra?

Tags: logging, sinatra, mongoid

I put next line:
Mongoid.logger = Logger.new($stdout)
but nothing happens. I want to see mongoid logging information in my console after each request. Thank you.

Comment: I tried the same thing and it works (rails 3.0.4, mongo 1.2.1 and mongoid 2.0.0.rc.6). What version are you using? Can you see logging data in the log/development.log logfile? What does Mongoid.logger say before and after you set it to STDOUT (in other words, if you put "Mongoid.logger" in the console, what does it print out)?

Answer (score 0):

I do something like:

```
Mongoid.configure do |config|
  config.master = Mongo::Connection.new(host, port, logger: Logger.new($stdout)).db(database_name)
  config.raise_not_found_error = false
  ...other settings...
end
```

in a config/db.rb file, which of course has `require "mongoid"` and some rake task, usually :console which requires this file before launching irb. [example gist](https://gist.github.com/2397516)